# Move sample public links to a Stack Overflow public repository

Tags: feature-request

It is quite common that people share public link for Excel and Google Spreadsheet sample files. It is very handy to facilitate people trying to help to be able very easy to reproduce the sample and to provide a solution on the same public link, and then in the answer document the details.

The problem with that, thinking in the long term, is that the link might not be valid, for example, the user removes the public access or the account was closed, etc.

The suggestion here is to move all such public access to a Stack Overflow repository using the same tool, for example: Google Spreadsheet or OneDrive. Doing this way it ensures that the link will be permanent. There is a meta question: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) that suggests that all the content should be part of the post. The reality is that it makes harder to reproduce the problem and at the end discourage the community to respond questions that require to spend a significant effort to just replicate it.

I am thinking about a similar mechanism is already available for loading images, that it stored in a separated repository that doesn't depend on the user storage mechanism.

This community relies on other people willing to help so the suggestion is to make it easier, so people can spend time providing an answer instead of reproducing the problem.

Comment: Related: [Shared Drive for valuable Google spreadsheets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368054/289691)

Comment: Thanks @Rubén it seems to be a kind of similar suggestion but for all the communities which is a great suggestion. Did i post this in a wrong place? I thought this is the place to make suggestion and tag it as a feature request, but I am getting negative votes so I am wondering if I did something wrong. It is not my intention to post something that is not appropriate, but rather to provide some suggestions to improve this community.

Comment: [Voting is different on meta.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): "On posts tagged [feature-request](/tags/feature-request), voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself." I would assume that people simply don't think that this feature would be a useful addition to Stack Overflow rather than an indication of your doing something wrong.

Comment: David: As was mentioned by Henry, your post isn't appropriate, just some people doesn't agree that this is something that should be added... interesting feature requests might get many votes, sometimes they flip from - to + and vice versa several times during the first week.

Comment: Related (this is as close as it gets to self-hosting): *[New Image Upload Support](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/)* ([Imgur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur))

Comment: Related: [The system no longer accepts code that is *only* on external sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267244/cant-edit-previous-answer-because-of-a-jsfiddle-link) (like [JSFiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFiddle))

Comment: If you haven't done yet, please read and follow the advice in [How do I present a proposal for change or write a feature request for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375365/1595451)

Comment: Could you add some  questions having links to spreadsheets that were needed to clearly state the problem/issue or that really helped the answerers to provide a good / well received answer?

Answer (score 1):

While I would like that SO have something like you are proposing, I don't think that this is something that will be accepted by the company and well received by the community.

By one side, these will consume material and human resources ( Google have changed their storage policy and now Google editors files, including spreadsheets, count against the quota, a new "review queue" will be needed, etc.), by the other, I have seen a lot of questions about [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) that include a link to a spreadsheet that doesn't work as a "external mcve", most of them are questions that are "too localized" (the only beneficiary will be the OP) that have only one answer providing just a formula or script without any explanation.

I would like that those people willing to help spend more time helping askers to write a good question and pointing users to good questions/answers rather than providing a formula or script that is not worthy to keep.

Related

- [Is it ethical to ask for a Google sheets file, when answering a question, even when such request violates a user's privacy?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304/1595451)

Comment: Thanks @Rubén you see the problem too. My suggestion is instead of relying on user's Google/OneDrive account is to establish a mechanism/interface to publish the file in a SO Google/OneDrive account created for this purpose.The account will be managed by SO, so we can ensure the links are permanent because it is on SO account. The reality is that sharing the links facilitate reproducing the problem and therefore getting faster and more responses. It is just to adapt to the new reality, people live in the cloud, SO should be do something about that to adapt to the new age. IMHO